# How to tell someone the location of a place using the verb "lead"?

Tags: prepositions

I know we can say:

- The store is down the street. (along the street you will find it.)

However, I want to say that a facility is at the bottom of a specific way. I wrote:

> This street leads to the facility that you're looking for.

Now my question is, should I put ***down*** before ***to*** in the sentence above?

I checked **"leads down to"** and the number of relevant results is considerably high. If the correct way for saying this is to put ***down***, or if both are acceptable, then what is the difference? (If there is any difference)

Comment: Both "**This street leads to the facility that you're looking for.**" and "**This street leads down to the facility that you're looking for.**" are correct.

Comment: but *leads down to* implies descent. Not the same as *walking down the street*.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo So, you mean that would imply that the street is a steep path? Thanks.

Comment: No. Merely that it descends significantly. It could be steep. It could be gradual. The destination is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good thought and research has been put into this question. Most of the reason the question even arises has to do with visual perception.

> We will keep going down the road until we find it.

This sentence will be universally understood by English speakers to mean: **We will continue to travel on this road until we find it.**.

In English, "**go down the road**"  will mean "**travel on the road**"   because of old perceptions,.
With few extreme exceptions, if one tries to follow a road visually into infinity, one perceives the road falling  in the far distance, not rising. That, because of the curvature of the earth. So, in English, it is  "**down the road"**, no matter any measurable incline or decline. I would not think most English speakers think height when hearing or saying "**down**" in this sense.

As to the specific question:

> This street leads to the facility that you're looking for.

"**down**" is not needed. "**Street leads"** supplies sufficient information. It would not be incorrect to use:**"street leads down"**, but only because of the fixed idiomatic use of "**down**" in matters of travel. Travel, in this case, can mean more than moving from point to point on the earth's surface.

> Sometime **down the road** will will need new regulations on this practice.

**Down the road** can mean into the future.[Macmillan Dictionary on line](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/down-the-road)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will wait and then accept this answer.

Comment: One more thing, what do you think about Tromano's comment: "leads down to implies descent.". Aside from the fact that there is no need for putting "down" there, I want to know your opinion about the information that using down would add? Does it mean the track or street would descend?

Comment: @ Cardinal.......if one needs to supply the information that a location  is in a lower point than other parts of a road or street, "down" will probably not help  due to its idiomatic use in travel.. "Down" will probably not put the idea of height in the listeners brain. Use "bottom" or "low point". I would not be thinking that "this road leads down to Smith's Store" means I will be at a lower point at Smith;s Store than where I started..,,,which opens another issue with "down": "down" can mean "south", "Smith's Store might be south, not lower.. No matter, so long as you know a road direction.